# Import Google font into JSF page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I would like to import this css file from Google into JSF page.

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100italic,100,300italic,300,400italic,400,700italic,700,900italic,900" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: You can do it the exact same way between `<h:head></h:head>`

Comment: I get when I use SSL filtered content because this is not content from SSL connection.

Comment: Have you tried change http to https in the link?

Comment: Yes but I can't do it every time on every deployment env. I need some solution.

Comment: Then just replace `http://` by `//` it will automatically use the same protocol as used in the address bar.

Comment: Read http://xyproblem.info before asking next question.